# Summing group of data in Pandas row by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm facing a lot of troubles in using Pandas to sum row per row a group of data.
I try to explain better.

I have a dataframe (see below) where I want to count the number of events "blink" in the event_code column that are present in each block (from 0 to 5 in event_block).
Assume that the number of rows for each block is the same.

```
               event_block     event_code
    0                 0         blink
    1                 0         blink
    2                 0         -1
    3                 0         -1
    4                 0         -1
    5                 1         -1
    6                 1         blink
    7                 1         -1
    8                 1         blink
    9                 1         -1
```

I tried multiple approaches to have an elegant solution but without success.
My idea was to generate a binary vector of 0 and 1 for the blink event and than sum for each event block but I always get the same summed number in each row for each block...

```
result_df['is_blink'] = (result_df['event_code'] == 'blink').astype(int)
```

As desired output:

```
blink_count     
1         
2         
0         
1         
0
```

Comment: can you provide minimal example and desired output? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I modified my question providing a minimal example and a desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First generate a counter with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html), then [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

```
out = (df['event_code']
 .eq('blink')
 .groupby(df.groupby('event_block').cumcount())
 .sum()
)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    0
Name: event_code, dtype: int64
```

If you also want the counts of `-1`, use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
out = pd.crosstab(df.groupby('event_block').cumcount(), df['event_code'])
```

Output:

```
event_code  -1  blink
row_0                
0            1      1
1            0      2
2            2      0
3            1      1
4            2      0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works! However, can I ask you how could I handle the same problem if I have another categorical column called "Condition" and I have to count the blink events inside each event_block in each Condition? Where should I add this new grouping factor? I'm so confused...

Answer (score 0):

Use [groupby.ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html), then [groupby.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

```
m = result_df["event_code"].eq("blink").groupby(result_df["event_block"]).transform("ffill")
result_df["is_blink"] = np.where(m, 1, 0)

summary = result_df.groupby('event_block')[['is_blink']].sum()
```

Output example:

```
event_block is_blink
1           2
2           2
3           0
```